# Can we express a SPD matrix $S$ in terms of $S^{2}$ in a different manner to solve a convex problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, convex-optimization, quadratic-forms

I have to find the Symmetric Positive Definite matrix $S\in \mathcal{M}_{m,m}$ that minimizes the function $f(S)=\mathrm{trace}(S)+\mathrm{trace}(S^{-2})$ which has been proven to be convex in the following question:[Convexity of $\mathrm{trace}(S) + m^2\mathrm{trace}(S^{-2})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325875/convexity-of-mathrmtraces-m2-mathrmtraces-2)

Actually I would like to find $S$ using a convex optimization solver which doesn't accept the expression of $f(S)$ because somehow it always reformulate the problem in a way to have a convex equality constraint. That is, the $S^{-2}$ in the trace_inverse operator is considered to have the following form $S^{-2}=Q^{-1}=(SS)^{-1}$ hence $Q=S^2$ which is quadratic but in a convex optimization problem we could only have as constraints affine equalities or/and convex inequalities.

And so I wonder if we can write $S^{2}$ or $S^{-2}$ in terms of S in different manner such that I don't have any more the convex equality constraint.

I think that this problem could be solved by adding constraints using the schur complement inequalities.

Comment: Hi! What solver are you using?

Comment: Usually to solve similar problems with [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/) on MATLAB I first consider the substitution $Q = S^{-1}$ so that your problem becomes $trace(Q^{-1}) + trace(Q^2) = trace(Q^{-1}) + \|Q\|_F^2$ with $\|\cdot\|_F$ the Frobenius norm . In CVX this requires a slightly involuted way to be written in disciplined convex programming, that is 
`trace_inv(Q) + pow_pos(norm(Q,'fro'),2)`